# Android: List files in a Dropbox public folder

Tags: android, dropbox, dropbox-api

After searching a lot on the internet, I've found a lot of answers on how to retrieve files from the USER's Dropbox. What I'm looking for is how to retrieve the list of files from a public folder that I've shared and is contained in my personal Dropbox.
Displaying the dropbox website inside my app violates the Dropbox terms of service, so how to use the Android Dropbox API (Core or Sync API) to retrieve the requested files?

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox Public folder itself doesn't offer a way to (pubicly) get a list of files/links. The Dropbox APIs, both Core and Sync, do offer a way to list files in any particular folder, but if you wanted to do that client-side, you'd have to embed an access token, which is a bad idea, given the security issue.

One thing you may be able to do is keep an index of all the links at one pre-defined Public link. Your app could be hard coded with that link and then read the contents of it to load in the list of other links.

Comment: It is not possible to index all public files and folders due to their large number. So how to embed an access token?

Comment: How exactly you persist the token itself (really just a string) is up to you, but the basic idea to use it would probably be to create a session when necessary: https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-1.5.4-docs/com/dropbox/client2/android/AndroidAuthSession.html#constructor_summary But again, this really isn't a good idea, since anyone could extract the access token and make modifications to the account. These modifications could potentially be malicious and would pose a risk to _all_ users of the app.

Comment: This is how I'm doing it:
AppKeyPair appKeys = new AppKeyPair(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);
         AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys, ACCESS_TYPE);
         if (mDBApi == null) 
         {
             mDBApi = new DropboxAPI<AndroidAuthSession>(session);
             String token_key="####";  
             String token_secret="####";
             AccessTokenPair tokens = new AccessTokenPair(token_key,token_secret);
             mDBApi.getSession().setAccessTokenPair(tokens); 
         }

Comment: But when calling mDBApi.getSession.authenticationSuccessful(), the following is returning "false" @Greg